# Is it true? if $P(P-I)=0$ then $P=0$ or $P=I$?

Tags: linear-algebra

We are dealing with $P \in L(V)$.

It sounds intuitively ok to me, but it is hard to prove it (if it is provable.)

I started by assuming $P \neq 0$ and $P \neq I$, however, I can't proceed more from here.

Is there any other way to show it's right (if it is right)?

Comment: What is $L(V)$ in this context?

Comment: Super easy counter-example that I haven't thought of. Thank you!

Comment: Consider $P(x,y)=(x,0)$.

Comment: $V$ is just any vector space.

Comment: More generally, any projection (any transformation that satisfies $P^2=P$) will necessarily satisfy $P(P-I)=0$, but if $\dim(V)\gt 1$, then there are always projections that are neither the zero map nor the identity.

Comment: Have a think why this rule does hold in, say, real numbers. If you have $x(x - 1) = 0$, then either $x = 0$ and we are done, or $x \neq 0$ and hence $x^{-1}$ exists. If the latter is the case, then$$x - 1 = x^{-1}x(x - 1) = x^{-1}0 = 0.$$Note the line of logic that fails to hold in $L(V)$: if $x \neq 0$ then $x^{-1}$ exists. This is true in fields like the real numbers, but not so much in matrices.

Comment: Another category of examples (although really just disguised versions of ones that have been mentioned already): any diagonal square matrix $P$ whose diagonal entries are all $1$s and $0$s satisfies $P(P-I)=0$, but there are many such besides $I$ and $0$. (Indeed, the fact that $P(P-I)=0$ shows that the minimal polynomial of $P$ divides $x(x-1)$, which limits the Jordan form of such matrices to exactly these examples.)

Comment: Basically, if a polynomial equation $f(P)=0$ in a *scalar* variable $P$ has $k$ roots $p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_k$, the *matrix* equation $f(P)=0$, where $P$ is $n\times n$, will have at least $k^n$ roots, because each diagonal matrix of the form $P=\operatorname{diag}(p_{i1},p_{i_2},\ldots,p_{i_n})$, where $i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_n\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, is a solution. In practice, the number of solutions may be larger or even infintie, because if $P$ is a solution, so is $MPM^{-1}$ for every invertible matrix $M$.

Comment: @TheoBendit: The conclusion holds in circumstances where no inverses exist. The real issue here are *zero divisors*: in the real numbers (and the integers, and the natural numbers, etc), if $xy=0$ then $x=0$ or $y=0$. This is false in matrices.